# Monotonicity of Legendre functions (of first kind) with respect to theirs order

Tags: real-analysis, legendre-polynomials, legendre-functions

I will denote by $P^m_l(x)$ the Legendre first kind function of order $m$ and of degree $l$, $m$ is a positive integer and $l$ is real number. I fix the value of $x\in[0,1]$ and $l=-0.5$. Is there any way the study the monotonicity of $m\to P^m_l(x)/P^m_l(-x)$.

Comment: Not a proper answer: I found that the ratio is asymptotically $\left( {\frac{{1 - x}}{{1 + x}}} \right)^m \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{m}} \right)} \right)$ for large $m$.

Comment: Thank you @Gary. Could you tell me more how to obtain that ...

Comment: From http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.3.E5 $$
\frac{{P_{ - 1/2}^m (x)}}{{P_{ - 1/2}^m ( - x)}} = \left( {\frac{{1 - x}}{{1 + x}}} \right)^m \frac{{{}_2F_1 \left( {\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};m + 1;1 - \frac{{1 + x}}{2}} \right)}}{{{}_2F_1 \left( {\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};m + 1;\frac{{1 + x}}{2}} \right)}}.
$$ Now apply http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12.ii to the right-hand side.